# Spark Streaming variable in UpdateStateByKey not changing value after restarting application from checkpoint

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I'm currently working in Python building a moderately complex application that relies on stateful data from multiple sources. With `Pyspark` I've run into an issue where a global variable used within an `updateStateByKey` function isn't being assigned after the application restarts from a checkpoint. Using `forEachRDD` I have a global variable `A` that is propagated from a file every time a batch runs, and `A` is then used in an `updateStateByKey`. When I initially run the application, it functions as expected and the value of `A` is referenced correctly within the scope of the update function.

However, when I bring the application down and restart, I see a different behavior. Variable `A` is assigned the correct value by its corresponding `forEachRDD` function, but when the `updateStateByKey` function is executed the new value for `A` isn't used. It just... disappears.

I could be going about the implementation of this wrong, but I'm hoping that someone can point me in the correct direction.

Here's some pseudocode:

```
def readfile(rdd):
    global A
    A = readFromFile

def update(new, old)
    if old in A:
        do something

dstream.forEachRDD(readfile)
dstream.updateStateByKey(update)

ssc.checkpoint('checkpoint')
```

`A` is correct the first time this is run, but when the application is killed and restarted `A` doesn't seem to be reassigned correctly.

Comment: Is `a = readFromFile` typo for `A = readFromFile`?

Comment: It is. I went ahead and corrected that. Thanks for catching it.